# Can't uninstall RPM package

Tags: rpm

I was trying to install and uninstall `postgres` 9.3. After performing a
variety of steps, I found that I have deleted something manually and now I
am not been able to proceed further.

What I am trying to achieve here is to remove all the traces of `postgres`.
I am not able to remove `postgresql93-server-9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5` package.

I am getting the following error:

```
[root(at)ZetaSearch01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep postg
postgresql93-server-9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5
[root(at)ZetaSearch01 ~]# yum remove postgresql93-server-9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql93-server.x86_64 0:9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5 set to be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================================================
 Package
Arch
Version
Repository                           Size
========================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 postgresql93-server
x86_64
9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5
installed                            15 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================
Install      0 Package(s)
Update       0 Package(s)
Remove       1 Package(s)

Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
error reading information on service postgresql-9.3: No such file or
directory

Removed: postgresql93-server.x86_64 0:9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5
Complete!
[root(at)ZetaSearch01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep postg
postgresql93-server-9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5
[root(at)ZetaSearch01 ~]#
```

How to solve this error?

Any help would be appreciated as I am totally novice to postgres and it is
my first time, I am trying to do something on postgres.

Comment: Did you try `rpm --erase --force postgresql93-server-9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5`?, sounds like something corrupted as you should able to do it via `yum` as well.

Comment: `rpm: only installation and upgrading may be forced`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using the rpm command instead:

```
rpm {-e|--erase} [--allmatches] [--nodeps]  [--noscripts]  [--notriggers]  [--test]  PACK-AGE_NAME ...
```

You can try it first directly and then with the --nodeps argument like this:

```
rpm -ev postgresql93-server-9.3.6-1PGDG.rhel5
```

Full command details at:  [RPM erase command](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-erase.html)

Answer (score 24):

This kind of error is likely caused by a scriptlet. When removing a package, RPM would run the "preuninstall" before removing a package, and the "postuninstall" after removing it. If the "preuninstall" fails, the package will not be removed.

You can check the scriptlets of your package with `rpm -q --scripts postgresql93-server`. For example, the `postgresql92-server` package on my machine contains this (abbreviated version to only show the preuninstall)

```
$ rpm -q postgresql92-server --scripts  | sed -ne /^preuninstall/,/scriptlet/p
preuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
if [ $1 = 0 ] ; then
    /sbin/service postgresql-9.2 condstop >/dev/null 2>&1
    chkconfig --del postgresql-9.2
fi
postuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
```

I guess your postgresql93-server RPM has something similar, and the last command (the `chkconfig --del` part) is failing causing the package to not be removed.

Two options I can suggest.

1) remove the package without running the scripts:

```
rpm -e --noscripts postgresql93-server
```

2) reinstall the package to hopefully fix whatever was broken, because then the "preuninstall" will be passed 1 as an argument and the failing code will not run.

```
yum reinstall postgresql93-server
yum remove postgresql93-server
```

Comment: The `--noscripts` did the trick.  This should have been the answer.